# gcs bucket how to get objects using filters [golang]

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to get list of objects which starts and ends with specific criteria
as example:

```
a/b/c/id1.json
a/b/c/id2.json
a/b/c/id3.json
a/c/id1.json
```

and we wanna query for

```
Prefix: "a/",
EndOffset: "id1.json"
```

expected output should be:

```
a/b/c/id1.json
```

and we wanna filter out other options and we don't know what the `b` folder name would be.

So:

`a` is always `a`

`b` is random uniq string

`c` is always `c`

and we always want the specific json.

As i am tying to achieve this with:

```golang
query := &storage.Query{
        Prefix: "a/",
        //StartOffset: "",
        EndOffset: "id1.json",
        //Delimiter:
}
query.SetAttrSelection([]string{"Name"})
```

or

```
Prefix:                   "c/id1.json",
Delimiter:                "/",
IncludeTrailingDelimiter: true,
```

and for some reason i am getting in return all of those files.

And of course i would like to limit the results as much as possible for better performances.

Maybe there is a way to use some regex in `Prefix` definition ?
like `a/*/c/id1.json`

Thanks

----------------------- ========= Edited ========= -----------------------

Please note that this is already implemented by me [storage_list_files_with_prefix-go](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix#storage_list_files_with_prefix-go) and do not work as i would like to have it. So the main question is HOWTO make this filtering working with the example I am showing.

Comment: What you are trying to do is **not possible**. Cloud Storage does not support your `b` and `c` filters. They do not exist. You must implement that filtering in your code after Cloud Storage returns a result set.

Comment: not quite right `b` exist but is unknown value, `c` exists and is known value same as `a` as explained above .. if these filters only support one level of filtering or unless u know the full path is quite useless ...

Comment: Prefix and Delimiter are extremely useful. They are not designed to solve your problem. They are designed to emulate a file system directory hierarchy.

Comment: yes if u know the path :) then u could do as `a/b1/c/` and so on for `b` to load file, but yes i think i will need to redesign the structure of directory as `a/id2/c/b1.json` as these values are own and passed to function, and @JohnHanley Thank you for having time and willing to chat with me about this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Key points:

- Cloud Storage Buckets do not have directories.
- The namespace is flat.
- Object names are just strings.
- The slash `/` character which is often used to separate directory names in file systems is just a character in an Bucket object name. The slash has no significance but can be used as a delimiter.
- You can specify a prefix and a delimiter to reduce the returned object list.
- Cloud Storage does not support regex expressions.
- The asterisk `*` is a character and not a wildcard.

Summary:

- You must implement additional filtering in your code.

[List the objects in a bucket using a prefix filter](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix#storage_list_files_with_prefix-go)

Comment: yes i looked at the example and was much easier fro me to explain things here using terminology as subdirectories, and as you can see above i was / i am trying to find the pattern with additional filtering .. but since u saying this could u show example of getting this achieved with those additional filters for this "string" `a/b/c/id1.json` so i can obtain full name ? and only this one :) thx

Comment: @nonus25 - I don't understand your comment. You must implement filtering in your application. What you are trying to do is not supported by Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: look above please and tell me what exactly u need to put into this Prefix filtering ... which part u exactly do not understand ? that this filtering is already implemented by me ? and doesn't work the way i need ? and your answer is obvious to say please implement  filtering ... from my point i do not understand why u keep saying use filtering where in above  you have examples showing already how i was trying to use `storage.Query`, i don't wanna do filtering on client side with `strings` or `regex`, best would be to have this done via this `Prefix` filtering.

Comment: Okay Thank you, so that mean i would only by able do this for storage object which have one level of delimiter like this `a/id2.json`, and doing a query for storage object  which have more levels i would need to know the `b` value to use in Prefix

Comment: could you explain me, what exactly in above i do wrong which is not supported by GCS ? 
Are you saying that if we have `a/b/c/id1.json` we cannot we cannot get these filters working if we do not know the value of `b` ?
Note i do not use `*` asterisk, `a/*/c/id1.json` like this.